# Issues while compiling C files in QtCreator

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors, qt-creator

I'm learning c/c++ and wanted to do some work with QT Creator. I am using a base64 class that just refuses to compile and any help would be greatly appreciated.

The error lines I get is

```
/QTDev/PolicyFrameworkDesktop-build-desktop/../PolicyFrameworkDesktop/libhaggle/base64.h:59: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'in'

/QTDev/PolicyFrameworkDesktop-build-desktop/../PolicyFrameworkDesktop/libhaggle/base64.h:66: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'in'

/QTDev/PolicyFrameworkDesktop-build-desktop/../PolicyFrameworkDesktop/libhaggle/base64.c:68: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'in'

/QTDev/PolicyFrameworkDesktop-build-desktop/../PolicyFrameworkDesktop/libhaggle/base64.c:: error: At top level:

/QTDev/PolicyFrameworkDesktop-build-desktop/../PolicyFrameworkDesktop/libhaggle/base64.c:320: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '*' token

/QTDev/PolicyFrameworkDesktop-build-desktop/../PolicyFrameworkDesktop/libhaggle/base64.c:373: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'in'
/QTDev/PolicyFrameworkDesktop-build-desktop/../PolicyFrameworkDesktop/libhaggle/base64.c:456: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'in'
```

Since I can only add one link at a time, the base64.h file is attached. I've been trying to figure out the problem all day.

http://rapidshare.com/files/435084122/base64.h

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The header uses the C99 specific keyword `restrict` that your compiler apparently does not handle :

```
extern void base64_encode (const char *restrict in, size_t inlen,
                           char *restrict out, size_t outlen);
```

However, the file also contains a :

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
// In case we do not have gnu extensions when including from C++
#define restrict
#endif
```

Which means that even a C++ compiler which doesn't handle the `restrict` keyword should not break on this code. You should check that you are actually compiling C++ (file extension might be of importance : are you including this file from a `.cpp` or a `.c` ?).

Comment: Hi icecrime, thanks for the quick reply, the file is being included in a c file. The links below are for the c file the generated makefile and the pro file if that helps. Thanks         http://rapidshare.com/files/435084121/base64.c http://rapidshare.com/files/435084571/Makefile http://rapidshare.com/files/435084682/PolicyFrameworkDesktop.pro

Comment: I have been looking at this for a while without success so I ended up building it as a library and adding it to the pro file as a workaround. This works for now but if any one knows a way to do it properly please let me know thanks. The example pro file is below http://rapidshare.com/files/435212949/PolicyFrameworkSpy.pro